# @HTML.TextBoxFor Performance inside Loop

Tags: javascript, performance, c#-4.0, function-calls, html.textboxfor

I am in a tough situation, help is highly appreciated.Long story short,
I have a view showing around 45 columns(cant avoid) , which has around 500 or more records. This is showed inside a  Partial View with 'FOR loop' with a **condition**. When the column has more than 1 record(make select list , check count [done in Controller]) then show DropdownList else show TextBoxFor. 
TextBoxFor is calling many Javascript functions - like marking it as Edited , showing tool tip , row highligting,  making it as only Numeric TextBox etc.
Performance as you would have gussed is really bad , when the records increase beyond 50. It takes 3 minutes to load and 5 minutes to save and reload the page. 
Using Entity framework for Data , with Lazy Loading, need to create Master/Detail Entities as I am receving Flat records from DB.
Tried Performance Analysis from VS 2010 , couldnt attach screen shots as dont have enough points in this site.
But I can see Number of calls to HTML.TextBoxFor over 1800 times... Is there any alternative to TextBoxFor which can call Custom Javascript functions

Comment: Try looking at the problem a different way...is there an alternative to displaying 500 rows on a screen?

Comment: I do have pagination using Jpages , but as this is client side, performance does not improve